# Vector Field Definition Doubt

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $\Omega$ and $U$  open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $F: \Omega \rightarrow U$ a smooth diffeomorfism. Let $ L \in \mathfrak{X} (U)$, and define  $F_{*}L : C^{\infty}(U) \rightarrow C^{\infty} (U)$ by $$ F_{*}L(g) := L(g \circ F) \circ F^{-1} .$$
Show that $ F_{*}L\in \mathfrak{X} $ and  $ F_{*} : \mathfrak{X}(U) \rightarrow \mathfrak{X}(U)$ is $\mathbb{R}$ - linear.

Trying to compute $F_{*}L(g) (x)$ I got:
$$F_{*}L(g) (x) = L(g \circ F) \circ F^{-1} (x)$$
$$ = L(g  (F(  F^{-1} (x))) = L(g(x)), $$  so $F_{*}L(g) = L(g)$? Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

It is more complicated than that.

First we must check that $F_\ast(L) \in {\frak X}(U)$, otherwise $F_\ast: {\frak X}(\Omega) \to {\frak X}(U)$ isn't well defined. That is, we must check that the codomain is ok. So we check that $F_\ast(L)$ takes smooth functions to smooth functions (1), is $\Bbb R$-linear (2), and satisfies Leibniz's rule (3).

Condition (1) is trivial since everything else is smooth (recall that $F$ is a diffeomorphism). For (2), take $g_1,g_2$ smooth functions in $U$ and $c \in \Bbb R$. Then:

$$\begin{align} &\qquad (g_1+cg_2)\circ F = g_1 \circ F + c g_2 \circ F \\ &\implies  L((g_1+cg_2)\circ F) = L(g_1 \circ F + c g_2 \circ F) \\ &\implies L((g_1+cg_2)\circ F) = L(g_1 \circ F) + c L(g_2 \circ F) \\ &\implies L((g_1+cg_2)\circ F)\circ F^{-1} = (L(g_1 \circ F) + c L(g_2 \circ F)) \circ F^{-1} \\ &\implies L((g_1+cg_2)\circ F)\circ F^{-1} = L(g_1 \circ F)\circ F^{-1} + c L(g_2 \circ F) \circ F^{-1} \\ &\implies F_\ast(L)(g_1+cg_2) = F_{\ast}(L)(g_1) + c F_\ast(L)(g_2), \end{align}$$

For (3), do:

$$\begin{align}
&\qquad (g_1g_2)\circ F = (g_1 \circ F)(g_2 \circ F) \\ &\implies L((g_1g_2)\circ F) = L((g_1 \circ F)(g_2 \circ F)) \\ &\implies L((g_1g_2)\circ F) = (g_1\circ F) L(g_1 \circ F) + (g_2 \circ F)L(g_1 \circ F) \\  &\implies L((g_1g_2)\circ F) \circ F^{-1} = ((g_1\circ F) L(g_1 \circ F) + (g_2 \circ F)L(g_1 \circ F))\circ F^{-1} \\  &\implies L((g_1g_2)\circ F) \circ F^{-1} = ((g_1\circ F) L(g_1 \circ F))\circ F^{-1} + ((g_2 \circ F)L(g_1 \circ F))\circ F^{-1} \\ &\implies L((g_1g_2)\circ F) \circ F^{-1} = (g_1\circ F \circ F^{-1}) L(g_1 \circ F)\circ F^{-1} + (g_2 \circ F \circ F^{-1})L(g_1 \circ F)\circ F^{-1} \\ &\implies L((g_1g_2)\circ F) \circ F^{-1} = g_1 L(g_1 \circ F)\circ F^{-1} + g_2L(g_1 \circ F)\circ F^{-1} \\ &\implies F_\ast(L)(g_1g_2) = g_1 F_\ast(L)(g_2) + g_2F_\ast(L)(g_1),
\end{align}$$

So now we already know that $F_\ast(L) \in {\frak X}(U)$, but we don't know yet that $F_\ast$ is $\Bbb R$-linear. Let $L_1,L_2$ be arbitrary fields in $\Omega$ and $g$ be a smooth test function.

$$ \begin{align}
&\qquad (L_1+c L_2)(g \circ F) = L_1(g \circ F) + c L_2(g\circ F) \\ &\implies (L_1+c L_2)(g \circ F)\circ F^{-1} = (L_1(g \circ F) + c L_2(g\circ F))\circ F^{-1} \\ &\implies  (L_1+c L_2)(g \circ F)\circ F^{-1} = L_1(g \circ F)\circ F^{-1} + c L_2(g\circ F)\circ F^{-1} \\ &\implies F_\ast(L_1+cL_2)(g) = F_\ast(L_1)(g) + c F_\ast(L_2)(g) \\ &\implies  F_\ast(L_1+cL_2)(g) = (F_\ast(L_1) + c F_\ast(L_2))(g) 
\end{align}$$Since $g$ was arbitrary we gor $F_\ast(L_1+cL_2) = F_\ast(L_1)+cF_\ast(L_2)$, as wanted.

Comment: But is true that computing $F_{*}L(g) (x)$  we have  $F_{*}L(g) = L(g)$ after prove the the linearity and the Leibniz rule?

Comment: The step $L(g \circ F)\circ F^{-1}(x)= L(g  (F(  F^{-1} (x)))$ is not correct. $L$ only take functions as argument, and $g(F(F^{-1}(x)))$ is a point. Parentheses are important here.

Comment: So taking a function $f$,  have we $  L(g \circ F) \circ F^{-1} (f(x)) = g(F(F^{-1}(f(x))))$ ?

Comment: I don't think we can say anything specific about $L(g \circ F)(F^{-1}(x))$. What I can tell you, though, is that in general $F_\ast(L)(g) \neq L(g)$, since $L$ "eats" smooth functions in $U$ and $F_\ast(L)$ "eats" smooth functions in $\Omega$.